# Should all the actions for a Redux app be contained within a single file?

Tags: redux

If you have a reasonably large set of actions in a Redux application should these be spread across different files in your action folder according to their domain.

Or is it best practice to keep all actions within a single file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to separate my redux actions by what they're going to do. Say, an action that'll add an *image* will go into my *Image*Actions.js, whereas an action that'll log out a *user* will go into *User*Actions.js.

This is a good idea for organization as large apps can have tens or hundreds of actions, and having them all within the same file can be unorganized, making it difficult to find specific actions.

It also prevents confusion, because the way to know which file your action is inside, you need to simply evaluate what that action will primarily affect.

Separating by domain can be confusing, as two different domains might use the same action, and you wouldn't want to be repetitive by copy-pasting the same action into two different files.

Answer (score 0):

I keep them with my business domain objects in folders so everything is neat and in the same place.

So different files. This also helps with separation of concerns.

On another note, having it all in the same file means you can't have the same action name twice.